# Angular2 ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular

I'm having some trouble adding bootstrap to my angular2 project.

As documented on https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/ I've installed ng-bootstrap to the node-modules directory by `npm install --save ng2-bootstrap` (`moment` is included in the same directory).

Adding

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {TAB_DIRECTIVES} from '@ng2-bootstrap';
```

leads to the following error `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ng2-bootstrap'.`
Also changed the path from `'../../../ng2-bootstrap'` to `'@ng2-bootstrap'`.

Both did not work. any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try like this - `import { TAB_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';`

Comment: tried this. no error in the terminal, but after rebuilding this one appears in the firebug-console `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8443/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap"`

Comment: I use the latest version of ng2-bootstrap too and import { TAB_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap'; works fine for me. Did you check if the node_modules folder indeed contains /ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js and d.ts file

Comment: ng2-bootstrap, was renamed to ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Here's an interesting article on how to implement bootstraps latest version 4 Alpha into your angular project with `ng-cli`. https://angularjs.de/artikel/angular2-bootstrap-scss-angular-cli

Answer (score 2):

After you ran `npm install --save ng2-bootstrap`, you need follow these steps-

In Systemjs.config.js, configure ng2-bootstrap like this-

```
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'ng2-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension:'js'}
  };
```

In index.html add these

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In your component you can use like this-

```
import { TAB_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

Sample implementation:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {TAB_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
   directives: [TAB_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App with ng2-bootstrap</h1>

    <tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
    <tab *ngFor="let tabz of tabs"
         [heading]="tabz.title"
         [active]="tabz.active"
         (select)="tabz.active = true"
         (deselect)="tabz.active = false"
         [disabled]="tabz.disabled"
         [removable]="tabz.removable"
         (removed)="removeTabHandler(tabz)">
      {{tabz?.content}}
    </tab>
  </tabset>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public tabs:Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1'},
    {title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true},
    {title: 'Dynamic Title 3', content: 'Dynamic content 3', removable: true}
  ];
 }
```

**NOTE:** Latest ng2-bootstrap version is compatible with angular2 RC4 version.

See if this helps.

Comment: thank you. I forgot to include ng2-bootstrap in the packages array.