# Adding ng2-bootstrap to Angular2 starter using SystemJS

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to add [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap#quick-start) [modal](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals) functionality to a component of a project that uses [angular2-starter](https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter)

Here's my systemjs.conf.js

```
/*
 * This config is only used during development and build phase only
 * It will not be available on production
 *
 */

(function (global) {
    // ENV
    global.ENV = global.ENV || 'development';

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'src/tmp/app',
        'test': 'src/tmp/test'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'test': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'rxjs': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'ng2-bootstrap': {main: 'ng2-bootstrap',   defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };

    // List npm packages here
    var npmPackages = [
        '@angular',
        'rxjs',
        'lodash'
    ];

    // Add package entries for packages that expose barrels using index.js
    var packageNames = [
        // App barrels
        'app/shared',

        // 3rd party barrels
        'lodash',
        'vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
    ];

    // Add package entries for angular packages
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router'
    ];

    npmPackages.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        map[pkgName] = 'node_modules/' + pkgName;
    });

    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
    });

    ngPackageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        map['@angular/' + pkgName] = 'node_modules/@angular/' + pkgName +
            '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js';
        map['@angular/' + pkgName + '/testing'] = 'node_modules/@angular/' + pkgName +
            '/bundles/' + pkgName + '-testing.umd.js';
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

I'm importing ModalDirective in to my component this way

```
import {ModalDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

package.json

```
 "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
```

This is the error I get:

```
 (index):55 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

In systemjs.config.js, you are missing map of ng2-bootstrap. Add like this-

```
'ng2-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
```

and in packages section, use like this-

```
'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension:'js'}
```

For more information, look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250671/angular2-ng2-bootstrap)

See if this helps.

Comment: After doing that, I get this error localhost/:55 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
     at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/date-formatter.js:2:14)

Answer (score 0):

Change you `system.config.js` map variable as follows:

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'src/tmp/app',
    'test': 'src/tmp/test',
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js'
};
```

And also change your import statement like this:

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

Now remove `ng2-bootstrap` from `packages` variable.

Let me know in comments if you still have any errors.